# PHP не выполняется system

Tags: php, linux

ubuntu 18, php7.2 требуется выполнить Program.exe, на шарпе написанный. делаю exec('Program.exe 2>&1'); , получаю run-detectors: warning: unable to exec /usr/bin/cli: Permission denied run-detectors: unable to find an interpreter for ./Program.exe string(62) "run-detectors: unable to find an interpreter for ./Program.exe. из терминала Program.exe нормально выполнятся

Comment: судя по ошибке, php не может запустить `/usr/bin/cli` потому что не хватает прав

Comment: пробовал даже chmod 777 /usr/bin/cli выдавать, простигосподи. пока не помогло